# Groovy Eclipse can't launch junit tests

Tags: eclipse, groovy, junit

In Eclipse with groovy plugin, I try to launch a test `@Test public void testToLaunch() {...}` but I have the error:

> The input type of the launch configuration does not exist

[image]

**What** `input type` **is in the context of launch configuration?** (can't find such an entry in launch configuration window)

Note: I try sts 2.8.1 and e3.7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens normally when the folder in which test case is present is not a source folder, please check [this post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/105810/vc/Error-launching-JUnit) as well.
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 14):

This can also happen if there is a problem with the groovy class. A few things to check:

1) Ensure that the class name exactly matches the filename (filename = `MyTest.groovy`)

```
package com.mypackage;
import groovy.util.GroovyTestCase;

class MyTest extends GroovyTestCase {}
```

2) Ensure that the package defined in the file matches the package the file is actually in.

Comment: Thank you !!  If you are using VS code Java Test Runner  and "getting The input type of  the Launch Configuration does not exist" ... Make sure your file and class name match.

Answer (score 7):

In Eclipse you can do

```
Right click ->  properties -> Java build path
```

Notice test folder is not available in sources. Add it.

```
Add folder -> Select test -> OK
```

Now rerun you unit test cases.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me, and I just restarted Eclipse (GGTS) and everything was fine again.

Answer (score 2):

I had a spelling mistake which lead to that error message. My test class file name was named `JUnit5Test.java` (with upper `U`) and the class itself was named `Junit5Test` (with lower `u`).

I was using Spring Tool Suite 4 (4.8.0.RELEASE).

Comment: thanks, that was my issue. I had similar issue, minor name mismatch between file name and class name.

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me. But these tests are written in Groovy. The problem I encountered has to do with how the IDE (Eclipse Kepler, Java EE) first opens a Groovy project after executing "mvn eclipse:eclipse".

The Build Paths do not reference the Groovy source files correctly.

To resolve, I:

1. Right-click on the project, select "Build Path" > "Configure Build Path..."
2. Select "Source" tab
3. For test and src folders (.../src/main/groovy, and .../src/test/groovy)
4. make sure "**/*.groovy" is set as "Inclusion patterns", not "**/*.java"

Hope this saves time for someone.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message when I head the test-class duplicated both in the main Java source folder and the testsrc folder. Removing the incorrectly placed one in the main Java source folder solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

2019 Update: This drove me crazy for days even with latest Eclipse and fresh installs (Mac, Grails 4, Gradle 5.1.1, Java 8). Some above examples led me to the solution.

My problem was more that the code I was testing included a mix of groovy and java src/main code. It gave me NoClassDefFound on the .groovy classes when I ran my Spec as JUnit.

Solution: I had to modify my Run/Debug Configuration to include build/classes/groovy/main. Then it worked. It's a little bit of a pain to remember to that for every new Configuration, but, it keeps me going. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create a Junit test in eclipse, make sure your **Junit test file is inside** `src/test/java` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Like others have already pointed out, it was about source folders. I had to change my source folder setup. There was an empty src-folder that disappeared after I right-clicked on it and selected 'remove from build path' from Build path menu. After that I right-clicked both java/src and java/test folders and chose Build path > Use as a source folder. And suddenly my tests were JUnited!

In similar situations I'd advice to remove all source folders from build path and add them again when you're sure you've got the right ones. Your source folders should be those with Java package structure under them. In case of proj/java/test/com/stackoverflow/main it's the 'test' folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is what resolved for me `(Eclipse Oxygen)`. I had already done what Robert suggested in the earlier post. I was still getting the error. When I went to edit the configuration for junit launch, I saw that the Test Class field just had the class name. I had to hit the Search button to the right. The Test Class field now had the complete name for the class

```
com.mycompany.mypackage.MyClass
```

With this I am able to run the `JUnit`. But I have to keep fixing this for every run.

Answer (score 0):

Found another way to cause this message.  The cause turned out to be an empty copy of `MyTest.java` under `src/main/java`, as well as the real one under `src/test/java`.

Think the empty file was a hangover from some refactoring and was oddly causing no compile errors either.  Deleting it enabled the test to run again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS code Java Test Runner and "getting The input type of the Launch Configuration does not exist" ... Make sure your file and class name match. [image]